# Why do I have to declare type at this line

Tags: c++, singleton

I was reading a book about singleton in C++

In this book, there's an example showing how to write singleton:

```
// Singleton.h

#ifndef _SINGLETON_H_
#define _SINGLETON_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton* Instance();

protected:
    Singleton();

private:
    static Singleton* _instance;
};

#endif //~_SINGLETON_H_
```

Here is its corresponding cpp file

```
// Singleton.cpp
#include "Singleton.h"

Singleton* Singleton::_instance = 0; // why do I have to type "Singleton*" at this line?

Singleton::Singleton()
{
    cout << "Singleton..." << endl;
}

Singleton* Singleton::Instance()
{
    if (_instance == 0) 
    {
        _instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

What confuses me is the line "Singleton* Singleton::_instance = 0;".

I think writing "Singleton::_instance = 0;" is enough for C++ compiler to understand. Because I already declared "static Singleton* _instance;" in the header file.

Why must I declare that _instance is of type Singleton* for the second time?

I've tried deleting "Singleton*". After I delete it, Visual Studio told me

"error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed."

Comment: I suggest you read about the difference between a **declaration** and a **definition**. In C++, the types for both must match.

Comment: class's static data members must be defined explicitly in exactly one translation unit as not to break the one definition rule. `static Singleton* Instance();` in the `class`'s definition is a declaration not a definition.

Comment: The must be defined in *exactly* *one* translation unit, not each translation unit, @40two!

Comment: `_SINGLETON_H_` is a reserved identifier. Do not begin a header guard with an underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you won't like the answer, but the gist is that C++ simply requires types to be specified on all definitions (with certain exceptional cases, where you may use `auto`).

Same reason why you need to repeat the types when you declare and define a function:

```
int foo(char);

int foo(char x) {
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite it's correct what's said in the other answers, I would recommend you the following implementation

```
 Singleton& Singleton::Instance() {
     static Singleton theInstance;
     return theInstance;
 }
```

Not only this idiom is thread safe, it's less writing, regarding your points about declaration and definition of the `_instance` variable.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is that the type for any **declaration** must match the type for its **definition**. If you don't understand the difference between a declaration and a definition, I suggest you do some research and reading.